# SMS to Twilio Number with Extension

Tags: sms, twilio

I'd like users to be able to text my Twilio number and have the text forwarded to various recipients based on the number's extension. i.e. texting to `555-555-5555,2` should route to a different receiver than `555-555-5555,3`.

This Quora answer hints that this is possible, but I haven't found any further documentation: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-send-a-text-message-from-my-Android-to-a-phone-number-with-an-extension-number

I tried using Twilio Studio to implement something like an IVR or message/response, but that only produced a text prompt which didn't seem to respond to the number entered after the comma.

Answer (score 2):

This not possible by appending data to the destination number. You would need to place directives in the SMS message body and have your Twilio (Studio) logic parse the message body to determine how to deliver the SMS (which Phone number to deliver the SMS to).